# SQL Trigger - Commit Update and CATCH Block of Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a trigger on a table that executes a stored procedure. The executed stored procedure has a TRY/CATCH, so that if there is an error, a row is inserted into a log table.

When the stored procedure fails, I'm getting the following error:

```
The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot support operations that write to the log file. Roll back the transaction.
```

How do I make it so the update get committed and the CATCH in the stored procedure is also executed? If I add:

```
IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 
ROLLBACK TRAN
```

to the stored procedure, then I get the following error:

```
The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.
```

Trigger:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trigger123] ON [dbo].[tbl321]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
IF UPDATE (status) 
BEGIN

 IF EXISTS (--some condition)
BEGIN
EXEC SProc 
END

END
END
```

SProc:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SProc ]
AS  
BEGIN  

DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000);
DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT;
DECLARE @ErrorState INT;

BEGIN TRY

   select @sql = '
   declare @error1 varchar(255),
   @error2 varchar(255),
   @error3 varchar(255)

   Exec SomeDB.DBO.ConfirmStatus  ''A10594'',@error1 output,@error2 output,@error3 output

   if ISNULL(@error1,0) <> 0
   begin
        set @error1 = ISNULL(@error2,'''') + '' '' + ISNULL(@error3,'''') + '' '' + ISNULL(@error1,0)
        RAISERROR (@error1, 16, 1)
   end'
   from jobs j

   exec(@sql) at [linked_server]

   update status
    set status_prev = 1

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH

SELECT
@ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
@ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
@ErrorState = ERROR_STATE()

INSERT INTO error_log (error_datetime, [error_message])
SELECT
    GETDATE(),
    'Msg: ' + ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR, ERROR_NUMBER()), 'N/A') + ', Level: ' + ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR, @ErrorSeverity), 'N/A') + ', Line: ' + ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR, ERROR_LINE()), 'N/A') + ', Error: ' + ISNULL(@ErrorMessage, 'N/A')

END CATCH
END
```

Comment: You can't. There's no such thing as nested transactions in SQL Server. if you need to do something like this you probably need to design an SP to handle your `INSERT` `UPDATE` statements and stop people making changes to the data in the table directly.

Comment: One option is to execute the statement you don't mind failing asynchronously, by leveraging a service broker queue with activation (this has a bit of a learning curve). With this approach, the statement on the linked server will be executed independently of your update, which may or may not be what you want (it will no longer be guaranteed that the statement is done when the update returns, but on the other hand, this may speed up updates because we're no longer waiting).

Comment: Can I put the try/catch in the trigger instead of the proc?

Comment: Yes, you can, but this is fraught with peril. If the error ends up dooming the transaction, you won't be able to perform any inserts and the whole thing will be force rollbacked anyway. I don't know if a failure to execute on a linked server dooms the tran; it probably depends. Some more information [here](http://sommarskog.se/error_handling/Appendix1.html).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to modify my stored procedure to not use a try/catch. This gets me what I need.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SProc ]
AS  
BEGIN  

DECLARE @error table (error1 varchar(255))

DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000);
DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT;
DECLARE @ErrorState INT;

BEGIN TRY

   select @sql = '
   declare @error1 varchar(255),
   @error2 varchar(255),
   @error3 varchar(255)

   Exec SomeDB.DBO.ConfirmStatus  ''A10594'',@error1 output,@error2 output,@error3 output

   if ISNULL(@error1,0) <> 0
   begin
        set @error1 = ISNULL(@error2,'''') + '' '' + ISNULL(@error3,'''') + '' '' + ISNULL(@error1,0)
        select @error1
   end'
   from jobs j

insert into @error
exec(@sql) at [linked_server]

if exists (select top 1 error1 from @error)
   begin

INSERT INTO error_log (error_datetime, [error_message])
SELECT
    GETDATE(),
    (select top 1 error1 from @error)

else
   update status
    set status_prev = 1

END
```